# Returning count of rows with rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to return the total number of rows returned when a query is limited so that I can return the top 10 results, with a "View all 63" link in my PHP. I guess I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT `n`.*, COUNT('id') AS `total` 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE (name like '%search%') 
 LIMIT 10;
```

But that only returns the first row.

Comment: I've added a `where`, if this isn't correct please feel free to roll-back.

Comment: It's redundant to have a "total rows" field with the same value repeated 10 times. Instead, just submit two queries - One for the top 10 records, and one for the count of all the records present.

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it works for you ...

Comment: @Dems Yeap thats the correct approach, except in case where you dbserver is behind firewall etc and round-trip from appserver to dbserver is costly.

Comment: @ejb_guy - Any decent DB Interfaces will allow multiple queries/recordsets in a single command.  Thus, one round trip.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT n.*, total 
FROM table n, (select count(*) total  from table t2 where name like '%search%') 
where name like '%search%'
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT n.*, 
   COUNT(select id from AStotalFROMtable(name like '%search%') )  as Total
   AStotalFROMtable(name like '%search%') LIMIT 10;
```

**or**

**Read : [MySQL: Get total number of rows when using LIMIT](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/mysql-get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit.html)**

also try out

[`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) - For a SELECT with a LIMIT clause, the number of rows that would be returned were there no LIMIT clause

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *    FROM `table`    WHERE  name like '%     
          search%'    LIMIT 10;    

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The first query will return 10 rows, and the second query will return you the number of rows which would be returned be there no LIMIT clause in the first query.

Comment: Here the subquery will run for each row returned. Will this not effect the performance. Also, as count is used in main query, should you not use group by or move count inside

Comment: @SpabbyPHP - go to the link given by me and read th article that is good ...help you to get what you wnat easily....

Comment: I may be wrong regarding group by as count is not using any col from main *from*